# Original values of cmd registry keys

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, registrykey

A batch file I downloaded changed the registry keys of cmd.exe to make the screen, cursor, and font larger. This wasn't a problem, until every batch file I opened had these same properties. Looking through the registry, I found the values that were changed , located in **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe**.
However, I have no idea what the original values of the D-Words in that key are. In short, **could someone list the original values of all D-Words in %SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe so I can change my cmd back to normal?**

Comment: If you open the batch file it would tell you what was changed. No need to search the registry for it. You learned your first lesson when making changes to your computer. Make a backup first. I bet if you Google search you will find the default values.

Comment: I knew what values were changed, and I google searched many different terms to try to find a solution, but found nothing that helped me solve my problem. That is why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience - not based on any technical information - you can safely delete any sub-keys under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` key. Those sub-keys contain console settings that override the settings in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` key itself.

I haven't experienced any problems modifying those values, for just under two years now (since I got my high-dpi laptop).

As for listing the original values... Are you on Windows 7/8/10? XP? :)

As far as I know there are no sub-keys under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` key on a clean installation. Those are only created when the properties dialog is displayed/edited from a shortcut.